# using variables for creating resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is it  possible to replace the resource name with a variable
Instead of this

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

I want to do this

```
resource "aws_instance" "$my_box" {
  ami           = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

where $my_box would be defined in my vars.tf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic resource name is not possible.

[Identifiers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html#identifiers)

> Argument names, block type names, and the **names** of most Terraform-specific constructs like **resources**, input variables, etc. **are all identifiers**.
>   
>   Identifiers can contain letters, digits, underscores (_), and hyphens (-). The first character of an identifier must not be a digit, to avoid ambiguity with literal numbers.
>   
>   For complete identifier rules, Terraform implements the Unicode identifier syntax, extended to include the ASCII hyphen character -.

Resource name is an identifier like function name in a programming language which is (as far as I know) static.

If there are python function or C function, we would not expect the function names can be dynamic.

```
def function(arg): 
   ...


void main(void){
   ...
}
```

Although languages such as Python can pass the function as an object and set it to a variable, HCL is not such a language.